# How to attach custom android keyboard to the android editext using android inputmethod

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:inputmethod=""
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />
```

I have created an android  custom keyboard,
 This edittext need to be input only from that custom keyboard only.
           Help will be appreciated.

```
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK4F4.png
```

Comment: show your java file.

Comment: check image link for java code

Comment: please learn how to ask question